# How to track instances of events over time for a particular user in Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, analytics

I'm trying to track occurrence of each instance of an event(button click) over time for a particular user in Android.
I created a widget and gave the goal completions as a parameter over the timeline by adding an extra filter of Active User type.

However It is showing just the count of instances of a particular event not the time of occurrence. And I'm fuzzy about what parameters to pass in Active User type filter? It just specifies new/returning, tried both but to no avail.

I'd be grateful if you could give me some pointers int his regard

Sujit